# Android Jetpack Compose BasicTextField scroll to top when get focus, how to stop it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When BasicTextField has too much content to scroll up and down, scroll to bottom, request focus and show keyborad, it will scroll to top automatically.
I want it stay in its original postion, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply handle it like this and  modify the code according to your needs

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
var verticalScrollEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged {
             if (it.isFocused) {
                 verticalScrollEnabled = true
             }
         }
        .verticalScroll(scrollState, verticalScrollEnabled),
             value = "LONG TEXT",
             onValueChange = {}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but If I set ScrollEnabled for false at first, how can I scroll to bottom of TextField before the TextField get focus?

Comment: you can do it like this; scrollState.scrollTo()

Comment: Do you mean for me to reimplement the scroll of BasicTextField, include fling?